# Cohomological counterpart of the K-theory of the Roe C*-algebra in non-periodic systems

Tags: reference-request, cohomology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, c-star-algebras, solid-state-physics

In crystalline insulating quantum systems the dynamics of electrons is governed by a Schrödinger operator which is periodic with respect to a Bravais lattice $\Gamma\cong \mathbb{Z}^d$ and whose spectrum presents an isolated component within it. The range of the orthogonal projection onto this spectral island admits a complete orthonormal system, called Wannier basis, which is a fundamental tool in solid-state physics. Particularly one is interested in the study of the decay properties of these Wannier functions. 
It was proved in the work "Triviality of Bloch and Bloch-Dirac bundles" by G. Panati that the existence of an exponentially localized Wannier basis is equivalent to the triviality of a vector bundle, called Bloch bundle, over the torus $\mathbb{T}^d_*=\mathbb{R}^d/\Gamma^*$ , where $\Gamma^*$ is the dual lattice of $\Gamma$. For $d=2$, the triviality of a vector bundle over $\mathbb{T}^2_*$ is completely characterized by the vanishing of its first Chern class. This class can in turn be identified with the reduced Chern character
$$
    \widetilde{ch}:\widetilde{K}^0(\mathbb{T}^2_*)\rightarrow \widetilde{H}^{2*}(\mathbb{T}^2_*;\mathbb{Z})\cong H^2(\mathbb{T}^2_*;\mathbb{Z}).
$$
Furthermore, due to the Serre-Swan theorem, there is an isomorphism from the topological $K$-theory of the $C^*$-algebra of continuous functions over $\mathbb{T}^2_*$ (with the uniform norm) to the topological $K$-theory of $\mathbb{T}^2_*$, so we have
$$
\widetilde{K}_0(C(\mathbb{T}^2_*))\cong \widetilde{K}^0(\mathbb{T}^2_*)\xrightarrow{\widetilde{ch}} H^2(\mathbb{T}^2_*;\mathbb{Z}).
$$
In particular, the existence of well localized Wannier bases is obstructed by the non-triviality of the spectral projection in $\widetilde{K}_0(C(\mathbb{T}^2_*))$ or equivalently by the non-vanishing of the first Chern class associated to the Bloch bundle.

Now my question is about the article "Large-scale geometry obstructs localization" by M. Ludewig and G.C. Thiang in which the problem of the study of Wannier functions is generalized to non-periodic systems, where there is no Bravais lattice to work with and so it is not possible to talk about vector bundles over the torus. However one can still hope to find a $C^*$-algebra such that its $K$-theory completely characterizes the obstruction to the existence of well-localized generalized Wannier functions. In the paper by Ludewig and Thiang it is suggested that the right $C^*$-algebra to consider is given by the Roe
$C^*$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}^2$, $C^*_{\mathrm{Roe}}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, which is defined in the article. 
My question is if there exists a cohomological counterpart of the $K$-theory of $C^*_{\mathrm{Roe}}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, which should be a generalization of $H^2(\mathbb{T}^2_*;\mathbb{Z})$ in the non-periodic setting. Calling it $\widetilde{H}^{2*}_{\mathrm{Roe}}(\mathbb{R}^2;\mathbb{Z})$, I wonder if the reduced Chern character can be generalized in this context, obtaining a homomorphism
$$
    \widetilde{ch}_{\mathrm{Roe}}:\widetilde{K}_0(C^*_{\mathrm{Roe}}(\mathbb{R}^2))\rightarrow \widetilde{H}^{2*}_{\mathrm{Roe}}(\mathbb{R}^2;\mathbb{Z}).
$$
Since I couldn't find an answer in literature, I would be grateful to anyone who could provide a reference for this problem.

Comment: You might be interested in coarse cohomology. I recommend you check out "Coarse cohomology and index theory on complete Riemannian manifolds" by John Roe (Memoirs of the AMS).